# The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request

Tags: powershell

I'm running the following script on TC (parameters will be resolved)

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "%ma.env.pass%" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("%ma.env.user%",$password)
$scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create(@'

Start-Process C:/Users/apr_ma/stop_env.bat -ArgumentList -Wait

'@)
Invoke-Command -computername %ma.env.host% -Credential $credentials -scriptblock $scriptBlock
```

The same code is working on one machine and gives error on the other. I'm new to PowerShell, could you please advise what could be root cause of the below error and how could I fix it?

```
[16:57:12]E: Step 3/15: Deploy - Stop (PowerShell) (2s)
[16:57:12]i:     [Step 3/15] PowerShell running in non-virtual agent context
[16:57:12] :     [Step 3/15] PowerShell Executable: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
[16:57:12] :     [Step 3/15] Working directory: D:\apps\TeamCity\BuildAgent\work\d7932d0c55f77e77
[16:57:12] :     [Step 3/15] Command: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
[16:57:12] :     [Step 3/15] PowerShell arguments: -NoProfile, -NonInteractive, -ExecutionPolicy, ByPass, -File, D:\apps\TeamCity\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell4985299986600715917.ps1
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] [host] Connecting to remote server failed with the followi
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] Error message is logged
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] ng error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in th
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] e request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepti
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] ng requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service r
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] unning on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is th
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] e WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and co
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] nfigure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the a
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15] bout_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15]     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
[16:57:14]E:     [Step 3/15]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
[16:57:14] :     [Step 3/15] Process exited with code 0
```

winrm quickconfig gives the following

```
C:\Users\apr_ma>winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

stop_env.bat

```
echo Stopping App services
wmic service where "name like 'App'" call stopservice
:stopping_services
echo . && timeout 1 > null
wmic service where "name like 'App'" call InterrogateService | find "ReturnValue" | findstr /v "6"
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto stopping_services
echo App services stopped
```